# Java Simulate an incoming stream and organize it

Tags: java, stream, stack

I have a homework assignment that is the following:

"Write a program which will separate a stream of non-negative integers into a stream consisting of; firstly, the integers which are divisible by 3, secondly, the integers equivalent to 1 mod 3,and lastly equivalent to 2 mod 3.  You program should simulate the incoming stream by generating 20 random integers between 0 and 100 and should use at most 4 stacks of integers to solve the problem."

I'm not very familiar with streams, my experiences with streams has been limited to simple reading and writing from files.  So naturally when I was thinking about a solution I was thinking I could just generate a file and write 20 random integers to it. Then just read it in to simulate an incoming stream.

This is where I start to get confused, because I am supposed to separate the stream in a stream(???).  I understand the math aspect of the separation: x%3=0, x%3=1, and x%3=2, but should I create a new stream here? So I would take the input stream and "separate" it into an output stream?

Then he mentions using up to four stacks and I don't see where I need to use to stacks to complete this problem, unless I should be using the stacks to hold the integers before I put them into the new stream?

Please let me know if my understanding of this problem seems logical and correct.

Edit: My current solution

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

/**
 * write a program which will seperate a stream of nonnegative integers into a stream     consisting of, firstly , the
 * integers which are divisible by 3, secondly, the integers equivalent to 1 modula three, and lastly, the integers
 * equivalent to 2 modulo 3.  Your program should simulate the incoming stream by generating 20 random integers between
 * 0 and 100 and should use at most 4 stack of integers to solve the problem.
*/
public class StreamSeperator {
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    /*
     *  Generate file to simulate incoming stream
     */
    int arr[] = new int[20];
    Random rand = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i<20;i++){
        arr[i] = rand.nextInt(100);
    }
    try{
        File inputFile = new File("stream_sim.txt");

        if(!inputFile.exists()){
            inputFile.createNewFile();
        }
        FileWriter inputWriter = new FileWriter(inputFile.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(inputWriter);
        for(int j=0;j<arr.length-1;j++){
            bw.write(String.valueOf(arr[j]));
            bw.newLine();
        }
        bw.close();
        System.out.println("Sim file generated");
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /*
     * Read file in and sort into stacks
     */
    Stack<Integer> divisByThree = new Stack<Integer>();
    Stack<Integer> remainderOne = new Stack<Integer>();
    Stack<Integer> remainderTwo = new Stack<Integer>();

    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("stream_sim.txt"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            int _temp = Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine);
            //divisible by three
            if(_temp%3==0){
                divisByThree.push(_temp);
            }
            //remainder of one
            else if(_temp%3==1){
                remainderOne.push(_temp);
            }
            //remainder of two
            else if(_temp%3==2){
                remainderTwo.push(_temp);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    /*
     * Feed stacks into output stream
     */
    try{
        File outFile = new File("out.txt");
        if(!outFile.exists()){
            outFile.createNewFile();
        }
        FileWriter outWriter = new FileWriter(outFile.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter outbw = new BufferedWriter(outWriter);
        Iterator itStack1 = divisByThree.iterator();
        Iterator itStack2 = remainderOne.iterator();
        Iterator itStack3 = remainderTwo.iterator();
        //first stack
        while(itStack1.hasNext()){
            outbw.write(String.valueOf(divisByThree.pop()));
            outbw.newLine();
        }
        //second stack
        while(itStack2.hasNext()){
            outbw.write(String.valueOf(remainderOne.pop()));
            outbw.newLine();
        }
        //thrid stack
        while(itStack3.hasNext()){
            outbw.write(String.valueOf(remainderTwo.pop()));
            outbw.newLine();
        }
        outbw.close();
        System.out.println("Out file generated");
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not very familiar with streams

That's the point of the assignment - to make you more familiar.

You're on the right track.  Decompose the problem into pieces: reading, organizing, and redirecting.

Create an `OutputStream` for each case and write the values that match your criterion to it.

Comment: I'm still unsure how the stacks work into the problem, and the assignment indicates I should separate the values into **a** stream.  Is there a reason I should create a stream for each case?

Should I use stacks to hold the integers after I've read the integers in and sorted them, and then create an output stream and then write them in order?

Comment: I don't think the word "stacks" should make you think of another data structure.  I don't think you have to sort anything, either.  I view it this way: "Take in a value, decide where to write it, write it."  That's where the multiple output streams come in.  Ask yourself: Is it possible for a single value to be written to more than one stream?  None?

Comment: Stack can refer to a stream?  

We studied stacks/queues before streams, so I still think he wants me to use stacks to solve the problem.  Also he wants the output to be one stream, so I think sorting is necessary.

I added my current solution above also.

Comment: Okay, I see your point.  I interpreted the wording differently.  I agree with you now.  I don't think the data structure needs to be a stack; if they have to be sorted, I'd say that any Collection would do.  You'll need one per type and a big one to bring them together.